# What is the minimum decimal which can be converted to float and then back to decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal, precision, converters

```cs
var t = (decimal)((float)decimal.MinValue)
```

fails with `error CS0031: Constant value '-7.922816E+28' cannot be converted to a 'decimal'`, but why?

`decimal.MinValue` is `-79228162514264337593543950335m`. It successfully converts to `float` as `-79228160000000000000000000000f` wichh is larger than `decimal.MinValue`:

```cs
(float)decimal.MinValue > decimal.MinValue
```

Why this value can't be converted? I understand it's something about the significand and the exponent but what exactly happen? And which is minimum decimal which can be converted to float and then back to decimal in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not printing the full precision of the float, so you cannot see the value that is causing it to fail.

If you change the code as follows:

```
var decMin = (float)decimal.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine(decMin.ToString("R")); // "-7.9228163E+28"

// Next line throws System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.
var dec = (decimal)decMin;
```

The value of `decMin` is displayed as `-7.9228163E+28`. To make this easier to compare, let's rewrite that without the exponent and compare it to `decimal.MinValue`:

```
decMin           = -79_228_163_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
decimal.MinValue = -79_228_162_514_264_337_593_543_950_335
```

Now you can see that `decMin` is MORE NEGATIVE than `decimal.MinValue` - which explains why it fails to convert.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It also strange what I see different result when using "N" formatting in C# Interactive window in VS and in console app, but looks likt doesn't work perfectly at all and only exponent notation is correct in this case. Looks like the minimum number is -7.922816E+28 (-79228160000000000000000000000m)

Comment: Writing to the console that way does not show the true `float` value. It is − 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336. Lower than `decimal.MinValue`, but only by 1.

Comment: @AleksandrVishnyakov: The smallest (most negative) `float` value within bounds should be -79,228,157,791,897,854,723,898,736,640.

Comment: @EricPostpischil jus try it and see working. -79228160000000000000000000000m is the smallest

Comment: @AleksandrVishnyakov: I am not saying that `decimal` cannot be converted to `float` and back to `decimal` without producing − 79,228,160,000,000,000,000,000,000,000. I was just pointing out the actual minimum `float` involved is -79,228,157,791,897,854,723,898,736,640.